# Gamemaker Studio Android open browser

Tags: android, game-maker

I am trying to launch a website from within an Android game. When the user clicks a button it should launch the website. open_url() and open_url_ext() etc. works for windows, but does nothing for the android export.  Is this possible with gamemaker?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been an android access problem, not a function in gamemaker issue. After testing across a range of devices and android versions I found that sometimes the function works and sometimes it does not. One some devices, I have to allow access to local media.  So to answer my own question -  it is possible in gamemaker provided the OS allows the activity.